# Vinyl siding gap on corner

Tags: vinyl-siding

I'm a computer programmer so this isn't my field, however I am a new home owner... Our new house has vinyl siding, one of the corner prices has what appears to be a 6inch or so gap near the roof exposing the wood beneath. Is there an easy way to push this price back in to place, it seems to have slid down, there is a similarly lengthened surplus at the bottom, also I'm left to wonder if it is standard to not have some method to nail or otherwise pin the piece in to place so it wouldn't slip.

[image: top from ground level]
[image: bottom]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some corners like yours are actually two parts--an inner part that's nailed to the wall framing, and a snap-on cover. You can actually see the inner component in your photo at the top. This arrangement allows for various styles to be used. Generally the inherent tension and friction of the two components prevents slipping like you've seen.

With a wooden block held snugly against the bottom of the slipped corner piece, use a rubber mallet or other tool to gently tap the slipped corner back into place. This would best be done on a warm day when the vinyl is less likely to shatter.

A small screw or rivet in an inconspicuous location, or a dab of exterior construction adhesive behind the cover, will help prevent future slipping.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I do not have the adhesive but I can resolve that after the holiday! Thank you so much. I was terrified that maybe it had been installed improperly and otherwise attached to affixed to the corner, thankfully the handle of another hammer worked to help diffuse the force from the hammer and that its unusually warm in northern Massachusetts this time of year. Any suggestion on the type of adhesive or will some general purpose stuff work?

Comment: Glad to hear. It would be a shame to buy a whole tube of something just for this. Try any silicone adhesive you have around, otherwise get a handyman tube of silicone or construction adhesive from your hardware store.

Comment: I have some modeling adhesive that's silicone and will bind to plastic. It's akin to rubber cement just a bit more durable, I know it's plastic safe so I'll give that a try. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. FWIW, I'm also a software engineer, but I was a carpenter/home builder in a past life.

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense. I mean I wouldn't have come to stack exchange if it weren't for the fact I live off of SO. If I can ever lend a hand in the Dev world let me know. My profile is always up to date.